# Qt QML: limit maximum FPS

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to limit max FPS of a QML app?

I get 60FPS and 30% CPU usage in low-end iten atom harware
with win32 Angle driver (openGLSoftware is unusable),
and I'm trying to use less CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether it's supported on the underlying platform/driver, you may try setting http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsurfaceformat.html#setSwapInterval.

So in your main:

```
QSurfaceFormat format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
format.setSwapInterval(...);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

Comment: Good aproach:  but I need to change QML loop time too. this time affects animation speeds, but my QML  FPS counter is fixed to 60FPS

Comment: may be a custom QAnimatordriver?